# Python2.7 バイト表記された文字の取得が分からない。

Tags: python, python2

すみませんが、お助け願います。
Python2.7 で、文字などを16進で画面に表示すると、`\x01` のような文字が表示されます。
この `\x01` の文字を変数に取得したいのですが、どのようにすればいいのか分かりません。

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('hhl', 1,2,3)
'\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

上記の `\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00` を変数に入れたい。

```
a = pack('hhl', 1,2,3)
len(a)
```

だと、16 になってしまい、この変数のバイト数になってしまう。
そうではなく、`\x` も文字なので len を 64 で取りたいのです。

以上になります。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @cubick様。編集ありがとございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\x01\x00～"` という文字列ではなく、`"\\x01\\x00～"` という文字列として取得したい、という意味だと理解しました。

### 16 進表記に自分で変換する方法

文字列からコードポイントを得られる組み込み関数 [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) などを使えば、この 16 進表記の文字列を自作することができます。

```
from struct import *
a = ''.join(map(lambda c: '\\x%02x' % ord(c), pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)))
print(a)
print(len(a))  # 64 が出力されます。
```

※マルチバイト文字が含まれる場合はこれだと上手くいきません。また Python 3 では文字列の扱いが変わっているためやはり上手くいきません。

### `repr` を使う方法

組み込み関数 [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) を使えばインタプリタで表示される文字列を得ることができます。常に 16 進表記になるかまでドキュメントされていなかった気がするので、**この挙動に依存して良いのであれば**次のように書くことができます。

```
from struct import *
a = repr(pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3))[1:-1]
print(a)
print(len(a))  # 64 が出力されます。
```

---

補足：Python 2.x 系列は既に End of Life となっており、積極的にはメンテナンスされていません。可能であれば Python 3.x 系列への移行をお勧めします。

Comment: @nekketsuuu様　早速の回答ありがとうございます！正に欲しい情報でした。